# How to convert a csv file to an avro file using PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am working in Google Cloud Platform and I am trying to use Pyspark to convert a csv file into an avro file. I have seen a lot of websites but I haven't been able to implment the solution. Thank you in advance. :)

Comment: Please share any code you have written in attempting to solve the problem. Users will be able to provide solutions by updating your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can read the csv file into a dataset/dataframe using spark and use databricks library to write it as avro. Something like:

dataset.write.format("com.databricks.spark.avro").save("your output path")